# Save content from XML into CSV file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, filewriter

I have below code which is going by all XML content.

Now, I have open stream writer on beginig, but I don't know how to add to the method:

bw.write

**ReadXML.java**

```
public class ReadXML {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

    File file = new File("C:\\test.xml");
    File outputFile = new File("C:\\test.csv");

    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
        printNote(doc.getChildNodes());
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private static void printNote(NodeList nodeList) {

    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

    Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

    if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
        System.out.println("Node Value =" + tempNode.getTextContent());

        if (tempNode.hasAttributes()) {

            // get attributes names and values
            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                System.out.println("attr name : " + node.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("attr value : " + node.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
            // loop again if has child nodes
            printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());
        }
        System.out.println("Node Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");
    }    }  }}
```

can you please help me with it? if you know how to resolve the issue will be great.

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "add to the method"? What data do you want to write to your CSV file? And by the way, your writer isn't open, it's null.

Comment: for now I want to save all the data, so tempNode.getTextContent());, should be added to bw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, still not sure what's exactly your problem but maybe this helps.

First, open the writer:

```
final BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
```

Then pass it to printNote:

```
printNote(doc.getChildNodes(), w);
```

Modify the method accordingly:

```
private static void printNote(final NodeList nodeList, final BufferedWriter w) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

When you have the node you want to write to the file do:

```
w.write(node.getTextContent());
w.newLine();
```

Don't forget to close your writer after you're done!

**Edit**

Examples for closing the writer:

1. Old school

   ```
   public static void mainv1(String[] args) {

       File file = new File("C:\\test.xml");
       File outputFile = new File("C:\\test.csv");

       BufferedWriter bw = null;

       try {
           DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

           System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

           // Open in try because FileWriter constructor throws IOException
           bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

           if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
               printNote(doc.getChildNodes(), bw);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       } finally {
           // Check for null because bw won't be initialized if document parsing failed
           if (bw != null) {
               try {
                   bw.close();
               } catch (final IOException e) {
                   // Log error
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Java7 and higher

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       File file = new File("C:\\test.xml");
       File outputFile = new File("C:\\test.csv");

       // Since Java7 you can use try-with-resources
       // The finally block closing the writer will be created automatically
       try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {

           DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

           System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

           if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
               printNote(doc.getChildNodes(), bw);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```